# Bootstrap, popper.js and vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4

In my laravel application, I have page that are rendered with vue.js. I want to add some popup in this page and use popper.js. Following the documentation, this lib is included in bootstrap.bundle.min.js.

I have this in my html page:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And I have this method in my Vue component:

```
        showCalendarChoiceHelpPopover() {
            console.log("click");
            $('#calendar').popover({
                trigger: 'focus',
                title: 'title',
                content: 'content'
            });
        }
```

When I load my page I have the following error message:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery___default(...)(...).popover is not a function
```

Comment: A side note, I suggst you to use a CSS Framework that is written for Vue Components like `VueBootstrap` or `Vuetify`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately I have not the choice, but I keep this for later.

Answer (score 0):

Okay mate so if you use Bootstrap 4 you need to include Popper.js

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function.
>   Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript
>   plugins.

And remember jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS

Comment: It does not work. Could it be related to the fact that it is used in a vue component, in top of the code (not mine) I have the following: `import $ from 'jquery'`, should I import Popper too ?